# Как дополнить строчку?

Tags: c++, winforms

Я создаю графики в case таким образом:

```
chart1->Series["АИ 95"]->Points->AddXY("07.2023", "52.53");
```

Как мне вписать в эту строчку название точки?(label)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39354491/5045688